# Docker daemon fails to start after changing systemd config

Tags: docker, server, daemon, mount, disk

I have tried to move docker `/var/lib/docker` to `/data/lib/docker` on my ubuntu 18.04 server , and I changed /lib/systemd/system/docker.service to :

```
FROM:
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd://
TO:
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -g /new/path/docker -H fd://
```

Now my containers and docker daemon fails to start even when I change the file back to previous one.

This is the output of systemd :

```
  CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
               └─15366 /usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
    
    Jul 23 16:16:00 user systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
    Jul 23 18:24:44 user systemd[1]: docker.service: Current command vanished from the unit file, execution of the command list won't be resumed.
    ~
```

Is there any fix ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem resolved by restarting containerd service :

```
systemctl restart containerd
```

The problem came from when I changed systemd , containered daemon was affected , and without restarting the daemon , I could not restart docker service